# Java Debugging: Source not found

Tags: java, eclipse, macos, debugging

I am having a problem with Eclipse where I can run my program just fine, but when I try to start the debugger, I get this message

[image: Eclipse Window showing error]

The picture is a little hard to make out, but instead of getting the normal debugging window, instead it says it is throwing a ClassNotFoundException, and is trying to dislay the source for Launcher$ExtClassLoader.

The thing that really baffles me though is that I can run the code just fine, it is only when I click the debug button that I have the problem.

I have also tried debugging at the command line with JDB, and I got the same error.

So far, I have tried Reinstalling Eclipse and downloading (what I believe to be) the correct Java Development tools for Mac OS X.

I have no idea what else I can try, so any help would be greatly appreciated. Let me know if there is any other information I can provide.

Answer (score 44):

Source not found might be legitimate for dynamically loaded code (e.g. Maven).

There are three workarounds known to me (after months of search):

1. Connect to a running JVM with the debugger and you will see the code.
2. Use Dynamic Source Lookup plugin for Eclipse from here:

   https://github.com/ifedorenko/com.ifedorenko.m2e.sourcelookup
3. Use run-jetty-run Maven plugin

   http://code.google.com/p/run-jetty-run/

I prefer and recommend 3. It works and starts webapp much faster than jetty:run.

Unfortunately 2. didn't helped me as it has issues with Windows paths with spaces.

I have filled an enhancement request on Eclipse Bugzilla and if you agree this issue "Source not found" should vanish forever, please vote for it here:

https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=384065

Comment: Incompatible to checkstyle-eclipse.

Comment: 3rd option really helpout

Comment: run-jetty-run migrate to https://github.com/xzer/run-jetty-run since 2016-01-16, and the eclipse install/update URL is  http://xzer.github.io/run-jetty-run-updatesite/nightly/

Answer (score 8):

Do you have the sources for the files that you are using. If you are using Maven (M2Eclipse) you could download the sources. This might solve the problem.
[image]

Otherwise you could go and manually attach your sources. Here is how you manually attach sources.

[image: Getting the library paths]

Next you have to attach the sources-

[image: Attaching sources]

Hope this helps

Comment: I'm not using Maven for my project, do I need to be using Maven to use this plugin, or can I just download the plugin then do download sources?

Also, how would I go about attaching the sources manually?

Answer (score 0):

The "source not found" is a red herring - there may simply be no way to get access to the source that is throwing the error, because it is deep in the guts of the debugger's class loader.

The better question, then, is, "Why is `scottrice.ChessPuzzles.ChessPuzzleDriver` not being found?" The only possibility that occurs to me at the moment is that something might be weird in your debug configuration. Did you debug the program by just right-clicking a file with a `main()` and choosing "Debug As" -> "Java Application"?

Comment: I used the button up top, though I just tried the method you described and I got the same problem. What should I be looking for in my debug configuration?

Comment: I'm really not sure. I would first try just deleting the debug configuration and launching the file again to create a new one. If that didn't work I would check the JRE and Classpath tabs and make sure everything looks default. You might also try switching to another Java version and see what happens.