# Eclipse not picking up Maven attached source on debug

Tags: eclipse, maven

I've downloaded the source for all the Maven JARs in my buildpath using Maven->Download Sources and `mvn eclipse:eclipse -DdownloadSources=true`, which worked! When I open up the build path I can see that the sources JARs are attached for every JAR file.

But when I run the damn thing on Tomcat 6 I keep getting "Source not found" page with "Edit Source lookup path" button. But the source is already attached in the build path. What isn't this working?

When I manually point it to the JAR file by clicking on the "Edit Source lookup path" button it works. And when I manually point it to the folder it does not work. Why isn't Eclipse or Tomcat picking up the attached source in the build path?

**Note:** I'm using apache-maven-3.0.4, apache-tomcat-6.0.16 and Eclipse Indigo Service Release 2.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Although this bug had the most votes of all bugs @Sonatype, it hasn't been fixed.

However I have filled an enhancement request on Eclipse Bugzilla and if you agree this issue "Source not found" should be fixed, please vote for it [here](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=384065).

You can found three workarounds [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11452410/695116).

Comment: The bug appears fixed now.

Comment: @cellepo I'm currently having a problem that [sounds familiar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37690353/eclipse-does-not-show-source-code-of-dependencies-in-debug-view) :(

Comment: Still this problem exists in Version: Oxygen.1a Release (4.7.1a)
Build id: 20171005-1200.

Answer (score 5):

I found this [com.ifedorenko.m2e.sourcelookup](https://github.com/ifedorenko/com.ifedorenko.m2e.sourcelookup) plugin. The link was provided in "*[Java Debugging: Source not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9474981/java-debugging-source-not-found)*".

Go to `Help > Install New Software ..` and use

> `http://ifedorenko.github.com/m2e-extras/`

to search for the links. After installing this plugin I was finally able to debug the source code of dependencies.

Answer (score 2):

Use *External* Maven instead of default *Embedded* in **Debug Configurations** dialogue.

Please see example screenshot below (menu Run -> Debug Configurations...):

[Configure external Maven](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D7nHg.png)

Tested environment:

- Eclipse IDE for Java Developers: Oxygen.1a Release (4.7.1a), 64-bit (from spring.io)
- Oracle JDK jdk1.8.0_144, 64-bit
- Maven: 3.5.2
- OS: Windows 10 Enterprise N, 64-bit
- Test goal `hpi:run` (sample Jenkins plugin)

Comment: Easiest solution if you have an external Maven installation.  Thanks!

Comment: On a debian-based installation, you can use `/usr/share/maven` as the path to the external Maven installation.

Answer (score 1):

In my case the problem was related with the source code attached with the "Debug Configuration", maybe some remnants form a migration to Maven.

I solved it by going to the "Debug Configurations..." page and selecting the configuration in case, then at the "Sources" tab I restored the defaults, which added all the project's Maven dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

Window->Preferences->JBoss Tools->Source Lookup

make sure you have check "Automatically add the JBoss Maven source container to all JBoss As launch configurations".
and under "Automatically configure the Java Source Attachment",
choose "Always".

this helps myself out of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think I fixed this for myself by updating my [Eclipse m2e](https://www.eclipse.org/m2e/index.html).
I think I had version ~1.2, and then updated to latest [as of writing] 1.6.2.

The [Eclipse Bug comments](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=384065#c25) helped me figure this out.

Now I can debug into my gquery-dnd-bundle-1.0.6!

Answer (score -2):

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-source-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${version.maven-source-plugin}</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>attach-sources</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>jar-no-fork</goal>
                        <goal>test-jar-no-fork</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

Comment: Your answer certainly is worth a little explanation. Kindly refer to http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer .

Answer (score -2):

The "target" maven project should emit it's source code before the "client" projects can have access to the source code. I solved the issue by using the maven-source-pluging in the "target" project: https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-source-plugin/index.html

Just use the following snippet in the pom.xml file of the target project,  make a release, and use the release version into the pom.xml file of the client project. Then eclipse can automatically let you "jump" to the target project seamlesly:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-source-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${version.maven-source-plugin}</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>attach-sources</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>jar-no-fork</goal>
                        <goal>test-jar-no-fork</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```