# Eclipse: Could not instrument class exception after upgrading to Spring Boot 2.0.1

Tags: java, eclipse, hibernate, maven, spring-boot

After upgrading a Vaadin Spring Boot project from 1.5.9 to 2.0.1, I am getting multiple `Could not instrument class...` exceptions when starting the application in Eclipse with `spring-boot:run`. Executing the application from the command line with spring-boot:run does not display the exceptions.

Without success I've already tried to clean the project in Eclipse, update the maven projects and to delete the .m2 folder.

The application itself seems to run without obvious problems, both if started from the command line or from Eclipse.

One of the exceptions displayed if I start Spring Boot from Eclipse:

```
[INFO] --- spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.0.1.RELEASE:run (default-cli) @ project ---
Could not instrument class org/hibernate/validator/internal/engine/valueextraction/ObservableValueValueExtractor: java.lang.RuntimeException
at com.ifedorenko.org.objectweb.asm.ClassVisitor.visitTypeAnnotation(Unknown Source)
at com.ifedorenko.org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.accept(Unknown Source)
at com.ifedorenko.org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.accept(Unknown Source)
at com.ifedorenko.m2e.sourcelookup.javaagent.ClassfileTransformer.transform(ClassfileTransformer.java:27)
at com.ifedorenko.m2e.sourcelookup.javaagent.Premain$1.transform(Premain.java:55)
at sun.instrument.TransformerManager.transform(TransformerManager.java:188)
at sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl.transform(InstrumentationImpl.java:428)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763)
at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:467)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:368)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:362)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:361)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.valueextraction.ValueExtractorManager.<clinit>(ValueExtractorManager.java:43)
at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorFactoryImpl.<init>(ValidatorFactoryImpl.java:140)
at org.hibernate.validator.HibernateValidator.buildValidatorFactory(HibernateValidator.java:38)
at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ConfigurationImpl.buildValidatorFactory(ConfigurationImpl.java:364)
at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.BackgroundPreinitializer$ValidationInitializer.run(BackgroundPreinitializer.java:142)
at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.BackgroundPreinitializer$1.runSafely(BackgroundPreinitializer.java:92)
at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.BackgroundPreinitializer$1.run(BackgroundPreinitializer.java:82)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

My setup:

- Java 8 JDK 171
- Eclipse Oxygen.3a
- Spring Boot 2.0.1
- Maven 3.3.9

Any idea how I can get rid of or what causes the exceptions?

Answer (score 1):

The issue seems to be caused by the [Maven Development Tools plugin](http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/maven-development-tools) in Eclipse. After uninstalling the plugin, the error messages disappear.

However, I was using this plugin to be able to see the sources while debugging a spring boot maven application (see [Eclipse not picking up Maven attached source on debug](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10569663/3049015)). Without the plugin, I am getting "Source not found" while debugging, even for my own classes.