# Eclipse does not show source code of maven dependencies in debug view

Tags: eclipse, maven

I've filed a bug by now: [495662 - Source Lookup: Not seeing source code in the debug view](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=495662).

---

My issue [sounds familiar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10569663/eclipse-not-picking-up-maven-attached-source-on-debug) but it can't be since that issue appears to be fixed. However,
I have set a breakpoint in a class coming from a dependency (via maven). The source code got downloaded but as the program reaches the line all I get to see is

> Source not found.

I've tried to add lookup paths by clicking at "*Edit Source Lookup Path...*" but nothing changed. I don't know what I have to add such that the debugger finds the sources.

It appears that this stopped working for *all* my dependencies.

How did I break my source lookups and how can I fix it?

---

**Could be important:**

I am running my tomcat from a maven build these goals:

```
tomcat7:run-war -am -pl mz-web-server -Denv=dev
```

but this hasn't been a problem so far.

---

Further, none of my maven dependencies e.g. `gwt-user*.jar` or `spring*.jar or anything are listed in the Source Lookup Path. There is only the "*Default*" path which doesn't contain it either - shouldn't those jars be somewhat listed there?

[image]

---

After downloading Eclipse Mars 2, removing my project completely and re-importing it without any `.settings`, `.project` or `.classpath` files, I am still seeing this problem. I can't tell if this is really an Eclipse bug but at this point I don't know what else it could be.

I also tried removing `C:\Users\<username>\.eclipse` and restarted the IDE without different results.

These are the included libraries under Maven Dependencies. As you can see e.g. `spring-security-core-*.jar` is included and the source is pointing to the local maven repository. Clicking on *edit* I see the full path `C:/Users/Stefan/.m2/repository/org/springframework/security/spring-security-core/4.0.3.RELEASE/spring-security-core-4.0.3.RELEASE-sources.jar` and yes, the file is really there.

[image]

My **Classpath Variables**:

[image]

Comment: Have you configured any other library source manually on eclipse? Even outside this project? You could have set it up as default path for sources to the entire workspace which would cause this problem.

Comment: @JorgeCampos Hm, no. Every single dependency is added using mavens `<dependencies>` plugin. I'm actually quite unaware what I've changed - I've been working on that project for quite a while now. If I edit the lookup path it flickers for a moment to a file and then back to the "Source not found" page.

Comment: Yeah, most probably there are a setting on your workspace to a path that does not have all the sources. This behavior was even listed as a bug on eclipse a while back, because of the events on the screen it sets the path to maven then get it back to the configuration. To fix it, click if the right button on the project, Run as then Maven Build... in Goals type: clean install, then go to menu project clean all projects. Then try again

Comment: If that doesn't work, go to your project folder, deletes the .seetings, .classpath and .project folders, back in eclipse refresh and run a maven build install

Comment: If it is a Maven project you don't have be concerned with. Eclipse will set it up again the moment you refresh it.

Comment: @JorgeCampos Ah, good to know - excellent candidates for the .gitignore list as it seems :D `mvn clean install` did not work - trying the other suggestion now.

Comment: Another thing so you should know, in a maven project everything that is not src and pom.xml file should be on .gitignore (unless there are folders of the project but not used by the code such as database folder for scripts, etc.)

Comment: @JorgeCampos Sorry, took me a while. Well.. deleting the `.project` file did not work that well so I left it there but I deleted .settings and .classpath. However, it's still not working unfortunately :/ I don't get this. Using Eclipse Mars 2 btw.

Comment: Thanks for the hint - I've tried to keep my repository clean but it seems I've added some unnecessary files. There will be a point in time where I'll take care about that - I did not invest too much in this yet since atm it's a one-man-project :D

Comment: Well The last thing you can try is to create another workspace. And add your project on that new workspace, but do that without that files (.classpath, .project and .settings folder). Another thing you can do is to edit those files .classpath and .project and see if there are some reference to the source code.

Comment: @JorgeCampos I think I'll have to try. The strange thing is just that if I click the "*Link with Editor*" button as I view a class that I want to debug, I am actually getting pointed to the correct project and the correct package of that dependency. So that part works - it seems only the debugger is the problem here :/

Comment: @JorgeCampos If I open up the maven build and go to "Source" then I don't see those dependencies in the "Default" lookup path actually

Comment: @JorgeCampos Okay, I've just completely removed every .settings, .project and .classpath file/directory and even downloaded Mars 2 (I thought I'm already using Mars 2 but in fact it was Mars 1). However, it's still the same issue.. I don't get this ..

Comment: That's really odd. Maybe the settings for the sources are on the .eclipse folder on your user home folder. That's the only thing I can think of given everything you have done until now.

Comment: @JorgeCampos I now removed `C:\Users\<username>\.eclipse` but it's still the same :(

Comment: @JorgeCampos From the looks of it (see updated question) I don't think these settings are wrong - I've just tried `mvn clean eclipse:eclipse` and did the whole re-import thing again. Still nothing... I'm not getting this .. this does not make sense anymore ..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know what the actual problem was and why it stopped working. As you can take out of my question I actually downloaded a clean version of Eclipse, checked out the naked project and imported it with maven without results.

However, I found this [com.ifedorenko.m2e.sourcelookup](https://github.com/ifedorenko/com.ifedorenko.m2e.sourcelookup) plugin. The link was provided in "*[Java Debugging: Source not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9474981/java-debugging-source-not-found)*".

Go to `Help > Install New Software ..` and use

> `http://ifedorenko.github.com/m2e-extras/`

to search for the links. After installing this plugin I was finally able to debug the source code of dependencies.

Comment: @JorgeCampos I'm currently realizing that this does not work 100% .. I see the variables in the Variables view - which is fine - but I cannot add expressions to the Expressions view and I cannot use the Display - this means I cannot debug static stuff e.g. like `SecurityContextHolder.getContext()` from the Spring Security framework which is actually why **I need this to work**!

Comment: If I run something like `logger.debug("test")` in the Display view I am getting "*To perform an evaluation, an expression must be compiled in the context of a Java project's build path. The current execution context is not associated with a Java project in the workspace.*" .. yay ..

Comment: That you can't do. The option is to download the source code for that library and add it on your project removing it from your dependencies.

Comment: @JorgeCampos Oh, so that is normal behavior? Since I got the source code and the debug information I thought this would be possible like as if I would really compile it myself.

Comment: Yes it is normal behavior.

Answer (score 2):

Tested for Eclipse Neon:

Press 'Edit Source lookup ...', press Add button for 'Java Classpath Variable' in dialog and choose M2_REPO variable and press 'Extend...'.
Then choose source jar file for wanted dependency from file system tree.

After that press 'OK' on all dialogs and relaunch debug process.