# Debugging Maven dependencies in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, debugging

I am using Bouncy Castle lib as a Maven dependency in my Java EE project that I run on WildFly. I am trying to debug it using Eclipse. I build the project using Maven, then run the WildFly server in debug mode, and then run my EAR on the server.

However, there is no source attached for the Maven dependencies. For example when a debugger enters one of the classes that are under Bouncy Castle library, it doesn't show the source code.

When I try to attach the `jar` with sources (in my case `bcmail-jdk16-1.46-sources.jar`) to the lookup path, the source code shows up but **the debugger isn't pointing to any line of the code and the Java icon for the class is hollow**. Here's the screenshot:

[image]

I also read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37690353/eclipse-does-not-show-source-code-of-maven-dependencies-in-debug-view), and tried installing the m2e.sourcelookup plugin with no success. I also tried following harvyS's advice and added `M2_REPO\org\bouncycastle` to the lookup path with no success (source code doesn't show up, even after restarting the server)

Here is a screenshot of what is happening after adding `jar` with sources to the lookup path:

[image]

Comment: Assuming it's a maven project, I expand the maven dependencies and for the jar in question I right click and then select maven->download source, and usually javadoc as well. This should copy the source and javadocs into your ~/.m2 directory. Then you should be able to debug a jar in eclipse.

Comment: The source is already in my ~/.m2 directory. I have a jar called bcmail-jdk16-1.46-sources.jar in my m2 directory. But, look at my screenshot and see what happens when I attach the sources. It cannot find the line of code that is debugged.

Comment: Yea, I've seen it before, don't know what to tell you expect its perhaps how the jar was built in the first place. Perhaps you can recompile the source?
 The stack is telling you the JVM can't figure out what the line number is. I don't think it's an eclipse problem.

Comment: Are you sure that server uses your jar?

Comment: @AleksandrM Yes, When I go to project maven dependencies in Eclipse I see bouncy castle(the exact same version) listed.

Comment: @user3362334 That doesn't mean that server uses that particular jar.